# Difference between XXXISelDAGToDAG and XXXISelLowering in llvm

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am currently exploring custom backend creation for a target. In the official docs of llvm https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html#basic-steps , it is mentioned that for Dag lowering we need to modify [Target]ISelDAGToDAG.cpp and [Target]ISelLowering.cpp. I explored few llvm targets. But unable to grasp the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting point because learning the backend code structure is not trivial and each target is implemented in a different subfolder under the Target
with several `.cpp`, `.h`, and `.td` files.

Since following is mentioned in your provided [link](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html#basic-steps):

"*Also write code in `XXXISelLowering.cpp` to replace or remove operations and data types that are not supported natively in a `SelectionDAG`.*"

Let's take this forward. I would answer with a bigger picture showing basic steps
prior to *instruction selection*, starting with the LLVM IR
step that is to the top-left and then citing [Getting Started with LLVM
Core Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782166920): [image]

> First, a `SelectionDAGBuilder` instance (see `SelectionDAGISel.cpp` for details)
> visits every function and creates a `SelectionDAG` object for each basic block. During
> this process, some special IR instructions such as `call` and `ret` already need targetspecific
> idioms—for instance, how to pass call arguments and how to return from
> a function—to be transformed into `SelectionDAG` nodes. To solve this issue, the
> algorithms in the `TargetLowering` class are used for the first time. This class is an
> abstract interface that each target must implement, but also has plenty of common
> functionality used throughout all backends.

> To implement this abstract interface, each target declares a `TargetLowering`
> subclass named `<Target>TargetLowering`. Each target also overloads methods
> that implement how a specific target-independent, high-level node should be lowered
> to a level closer to the one of this machine. As expected, only a small subset of
> nodes must be lowered in this way, while the majority of the others are matched
> and replaced at instruction selection. For instance, in `SelectionDAG` from `sum. bc`, the `X86TargetLowering::LowerReturn()` method (see `lib/Target/X86/ X86ISelLowering.cpp`) is used to lower the IR `ret` instruction. While doing this,
> it generates the `X86ISD::RET_FLAG` node, which copies the function result to `EAX`—a
> target-specific way to handle the function return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  "As expected, only a small subset of nodes must be lowered in this way, while the majority of the others are matched and replaced at instruction selection..." , this give me lot of sense. Then [Target]ISelDAGToDAG.cpp  , is for instruction selection is it?

Comment: Exactly! ```[Target]ISelDAGToDAG.cpp``` is for instruction selection. For instance, if your target is SPARC then you use this  [ISelDAGToDAG.cpp](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.29/src/lib/Target/Sparc/SparcISelDAGToDAG.cpp.auto.html) for instruction selection.